# bash variable being passed to external program (bc) as string?

Tags: bash, shell, bc

i have a shell script with the following:

```
    filesize=22
    incommon=25
    num=$(bc <<< 'scale=2; ($incommon / $filesize) * 100')
```

output:

(standard_in) 1: illegal character: $

(standard_in) 1: illegal character: $

if i replace ($incommon / $filesize) with (22 / 55) for example it works fine. 
How can i get my variables passed into bc in this case?

Comment: Switch to *double* quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bash` treats words enclosed in single quotes (apostrophes `'`) as
literal.

That is,

```
$ filesize=22
$ incommon=25
$ printf "%s\n" 'scale=2; ($incommon / $filesize) * 100)'
scale=2; ($incommon / $filesize) * 100)
```

Inside double quotes (`"`), `bash` treats these characters specially:

- backquote (`` ` ``)
- dollar sign (`$`)
- backslash (`\`)
- *sometimes* exclamation point (`!`)

You want:

```
$ printf "%s\n" "scale=2; ($incommon / $filesize) * 100)"
scale=2; (25 / 22) * 100)
```

Specifically:

```
$ filesize=22
$ incommon=25
$ num="$(bc <<< "scale=2; ($incommon / $filesize ) * 100")"
$ printf "%s\n" "$num"
113.00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can instead use below command :

```
num=$(echo "scale=2; ($incommon/$filesize) * 100" | bc )
```

As suggested by Charles, this can be done by switching from `'` to `"` quotes.

```
num=$(bc <<< "scale=2; ($incommon / $filesize) * 100")
```

Comment: The only important difference (for purposes of answering the OP's question) is that between single and double quotes. Using a pipe actually makes this *slower* than the OP's original code (`foo <<<"bar"` creates a temporary file with `bar` in it and redirects stdin of `foo` from that file; on a modern system where `/tmp` is mounted with an in-memory filesystem, that's cheaper than `fork()`ing off a subshell to be the left-hand side of a pipeline, as the initial revision of this answer suggests).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks a lot for the explanation.  Quotes are the only reason here.